# Cancel signal from Swift not reaching C task

Tags: c, swift, task, cancellation

I have a Swift initializer kicking off a C task with the standard argc/argv arguments, which works fine but I wanted to pass a pointer to a kill signal (isCancelled) so it can do some cleanup when I close the parent Swift program. In my test here, where I just wait 10 seconds before cancelling the task, I'm able to pass the pointer but the pointed value doesn't change when I cancel the task. Here is the code - the print shows the isCancelled is true after cancelling but my C Task (myClient) always sees 0 for the value of *isCancelled:

```
    init() {
        let myClientTask: Task = Task {
            let argc: CInt = 2
            var argv: [UnsafePointer<CChar>?] = [("IndigoPolarAlignAid" as NSString).utf8String,("2" as NSString).utf8String,nil]
            var isCancelled: Bool = Task.isCancelled
            _ = myClient(argc, &argv, &isCancelled)
        }
        let _: Task = Task {
            sleep(10) // Seconds
            print("Timesup!")
            myClientTask.cancel()
            print("SWClient: isCancelled is \(myClientTask.isCancelled)")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yeah that won't work - you are passing a reference to your *local* `isCancelled` to `myClient`, not `Task.isCancelled`. Also you are not supposed to use `sleep` in Swift Concurrency. Can you show a [mcve] of how `myClient` is implemented, including how you "always sees 0"? Is `myClient` an long-running loop that checks for `isCancelled` in each iteration? Seeing how you are passing argc and argv, is `myClient` actually another *process* or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, `isCancelled` is just a local variable and it is assigned exactly once. It has no connection to the Task's `isCancelled` property other than being initialized with its value at some point. What you want here is a cancellation handler that will run when the Task is cancelled.

If you want to pass a C pointer you can read, it would be along these lines:

```
let myClientTask: Task = Task {
    let argc: CInt = 2
    var argv: [UnsafePointer<CChar>?] = [("IndigoPolarAlignAid" as NSString).utf8String,("2" as NSString).utf8String,nil]

    let isCancelled = UnsafeMutablePointer<Bool>.allocate(capacity: 1)
    isCancelled.initialize(to: Task.isCancelled)
    defer { isCancelled.deallocate() }

    await withTaskCancellationHandler {
        _ = myClient(argc, &argv, isCancelled)
    } onCancel: {
        isCancelled.pointee = true
    }
}
```

That said, this isn't thread-safe (reading and writing through a pointer on different threads without a lock isn't defined behavior). It would be better to pass an atomic type rather than a `BOOL*`, but what type to use depends a bit on your C code, though I would check out [Swift Atomics](https://github.com/apple/swift-atomics), which should interoperate with C well without having to go to pthreads. (I haven't tried to pass atomics across languages this way; someone else may have a more complete answer for that.)

I would generally recommend not doing it this way, and instead making another C function you can call in `onCancel` that will take care of shutting things down.

Also, as Sweeper points out, your `sleep` should be:

```
try await Task.sleep(for: .seconds(10))
```

Comment: Thanks Rob, that looks interesting. I'll give it a try and look into Atomics tonight. But your last comment about another C function I can call on cancel does look best but here again I don't see how I would do it. The C task I'm launching is basically operating on its own and I look for its products in the swift code. The reason I'm trying to send a cancel is so the C task can disconnect from some devices before it exits, otherwise the devices are allocated to the C task until manually disconnected by the server.

Comment: I was also assuming that if I terminate my Swift app, it would automatically cancel the child process C task, if not, I can work out something.

Comment: I tried your code this morning quickly and worked perfectly! Thanks for such a helpful response :D

Comment: Note that there is no child process here. Calling `main` does not create a new process. In your code, it's just a C function that happens to be called `main`. So it will definitely be terminated if the Swift process is terminated, unless it forks its own child processes.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Concurrency was what I was after but  I guess I was misleading myself a bit